# Not able to convert repository object to AnyObject for import

Tags: swift, realm

I need to bulk import a json data set of approximately 30,000 records into a Realm database.

My decodable setup for the repository object:

```
struct Repository {
    let xxxx:Int
    let xxxx:String
    let xxxx:String
    let xxxx:Int
    let xxxx:String
    let xxxx:String
    let xxxx:String
}

extension Repository : Decodable {
    static func decode(json: AnyObject) throws -> Repository {
        return try Repository(
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx"
        )
    }
}
```

For the realm import I have:

```
                    let config = Realm.Configuration(
                        path: utility.getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent("Meta.realm"),
                        readOnly: false)

                    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

                    try! realm.write {
                        let json = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
                        let repo = try! [Repository].decode(json)

                        realm.create(Meta.self, value: repo, update: true)
                    }
```

The problem is the repo object is of a custom class/object type for Decodable, and is not convertable to AnyObject for the value label in the realm.create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm requires your objects derive from a special class called 'Object'.

You will need to change your struct into a class and ensure you derive from Object:

```
class Repository : Object {
    dynamic var xxxx:Int
    dynamic var xxxx:String
    dynamic var xxxx:String
    dynamic var xxxx:Int
    dynamic var xxxx:String
    dynamic var xxxx:String
    dynamic var xxxx:String
}

extension Repository : Decodable {
    static func decode(json: AnyObject) throws -> Repository {
        return try Repository(
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx",
            xxxx: json => "xxxx"
        )
    }
}
```

//Now you should be able to save your Repository object into Realm.

Comment: No luck unfortunately, making the above changes generates a bunch of errors.  'Method decode in non-final class Repository must return self to conform to protocol Decodable'  As well as Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Repository'.

The code above is per Decodable's documentation, which unfortunately doesn't return an Object although per Realm's documentation it 'should' work lol.

Comment: Your answer did however lead me in the correct direction.  I did have to turn the struct into a class and eliminate the extension.

Ended up just defining it as class Repository: Object, Decodable and then creating an initializer and throw etc.  That worked :)